# Authorization and authentication in Strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Strongloop. Strongloop gives built in User model. I want to extend the User model to be saved in Mongodb  Also I want to make authenticated requests once a user in logged. By authenticated requests I mean, when a user logs in an access token is generated and that access token is required in processing further APIs for different models.

The tutorials does not seem to help much.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The built-in user model already does all of the things you mentioned, sounds like all you need is a front-end that interacts with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate access token for the extended User model and create user in mongodb. Also i have inherited the role object in the same way as user. I am creating a "creator" role and storing it in mongo. Also i have inherited the rolemapping model to extend it to mongo. Now when i am trying to assign a user this "creator" role, the user gets assigned to the role but the extended role mapping do not have any object.
What i want is assign a user this "creator" role and then provide access rights over other models based on this role?
How do i do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
User.settings.acls.push({
    'accessType': 'EXECUTE',
    'principalType': 'ROLE',
    'principalId': '$everyone',
    'permission': 'ALLOW',
    'property': 'replacePassword'
})
```

directly add acl in acls